# Reverse bits in an integer : stoi exception

Tags: c++, string

I am getting out of range exception when using `stoi`. I am trying to reverse bits of an integer by first putting the bits in a string and then converting that string to integer using stoi.

```
uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
    string nu_bits;
    for(int i=0; i<32;i++){
       // cout<<((n>>i)&1);
       nu_bits.push_back(((n>>i)&1)+'0');
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<stoi(nu_bits);
    return n;
}
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  stoi

Comment: What is the string?

Comment: FWIW, `std::bitset` makes converting an integer into a bit-string much easier. i.e: `auto bit_string = std::bitset<32>(n).to_string()`

Comment: @user253751 string is nu_bits

Comment: @user968000 yes and can you tell us what the string is, perhaps by printing it out?

Answer (score 3):

By default, [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) expects a string in base10 (decimal) format.  But you are passing it a string in base2 (binary) format instead.  When that base2 string is *interpreted* in base10, if the result would exceed the bounds of an `int` then a `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown:

> Exceptions
>
> - `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion could be performed
> - **`std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (`std::strtol` or `std::strtoll`) sets `errno` to `ERANGE`.**

`std::stoi()` has an optional `base` parameter, which you can set to 2 for binary, eg:

```
cout << stoi(nu_bits, nullptr, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reversing bits by converting to string and back is very ineffective and as you do bits manipulation already just add a little more:

```
uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
    uint32_t r = 0;
    for( int sh = 1; n; n >>= 1 ) 
        r |= (n & 1) << (32 - sh++);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: After a lot of years I continue to see this kind of bit manipulation like coming from a different kind of mind (a very clever mind that doesn't work like mere mortals) and I admire it. I think I can arrive to that but I know it would never be my first your solution. Just out of curiosity: how much time it take to see your solution?